# separating dependent and independent variables

Tags: python, data-science

I have built a linear regression model but don't know what is the need to separate dependent and independent variables

can someone explain the code??

```
x = data.iloc[:, 0:1].values
y = data.iloc[:, 1]
```

Comment: could you explain further? more context as to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

A machine learning model simply works this way: you give it a bunch of inputs and outputs. Then, when a model is trained, when you give it an input, you expect an output.

So in the code you gave, `x` is input, and `y` is output, to train the model. AFAIK, most machine learning frameworks expect inputs and outputs seperately (e.g: [Keras' fit method](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)). Thus you seperate them before feed into the model.

Comment: Is this required to be done only in Python. Is it not required in R?

Comment: The machine learning part is the same, platform-independent. The `x` and `y` part may change from library to library. E.g. some library may not require seperating them; but it probably will have some other restrictions to do that. I don't know the situation in R generally.